# Use List Box with Multiple Selection in Query

Tags: ms-access, listbox

Given I've created an Access Form with a ListBox; `property > other > Multi Select = Extended`; which permits multiple selections.

User selects multiple items.

Clicks a button that creates a report in "Print Preview"; but this report is based on the query, and the query is based on the values in the form.

This is accomplished by using this in the query when viewing in Access Query Design View (not SQL):

```
Like ([forms]![padc]![V2])
```

Where the form name is `padc` and the value to compare is `V2`.

Previously, rather than the ListBox that might show 10 options, `V2` was just a field with one value. A user would either type a partial value, such as `jack*`, and the report would pull every instance where this value began with `jack`; whether that was `jack`, or `jackie`, or `jacko`, or `jackson`, etc. The `LIKE` part of this permitted the "fuzzy" logic bringing about varied results. The query would run, and the report would show all the records with anything starting with `jack`.

My goal, really, is to have a user select one, two or three, or all the available options in this box, and have the report respond correctly.

I believe the ListBox will let me do this, provided I have all the right names in the table that is the source of the options available to choose from.

I set the listbox to "multi-select" to enable multiple selections on the form.
The form is happy. It can let me click/highlight one or several items from the list.

The query is not happy.

For the field V2, neither

```
Like ([forms]![padc]![V2])
```

nor

```
=([forms]![padc]![V2])
```

Will retrieve records to populate the report; regardless of whether or not just one value in ListBox is selected or multiple values. (`Like` = fuzzy, and `=` means exact match.)

Neither work.

Of course, if the query won't perform, then the report won't perform either.

How can I write the correct query in Access, using "Query View = Design View" and or SQL to get this to function properly?

If the answer is "it can't be done without using VBA" then please point me to the VBA solution that a 5-yr old can understand, because I have zero experience using VBA.

Folks have recommended I use VBA; specifically that I should incorporate the "`IN()`   IN function" in some manner; but I don't comprehend this solution at all.

I admit to being ignorant; not stupid; but ignorant.

Comment: Can manually build IN() criteria in a query object but it cannot be dynamic. Requires VBA code to build the criteria and apply to report when opening. If Allen Browne can't help, then maybe no one can http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html.

Comment: AFAIK, cannot mix.

Comment: AFAIK?  wth is "AFAIK?

Comment: As Far As I Know.